# get specific field data from another table in django

Tags: python, django

i have a table in models.py with class name `registration` and another table `profileimage` with foreignkey relation with registration model now i want to
get  verify the email address by using profileimage table

**models.py**

```
class Registration(models.Model):

YourName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,verbose_name='email')
password = models.CharField(max_length=254,verbose_name='password',null=True)
PhoneNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True,verbose_name='email')
CompanyName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
WebSiteName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
NumberOfEmplyes = models.IntegerField(null=True)
YourRoleInCompany = models.CharField(max_length=100)
SoftwareUsedBefore = models.CharField(max_length=30)
Turnout2017 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
Turnover2016 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
Description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
ClientArgument = models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True)
PaymentsPlan = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)




class ProfileImages(models.Model):

MemeberName = models.OneToOneField('Registration',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_image',default=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "user profile image"
```

now for example i have email adress which i get from sessions now e.g example@stack.com now i want to use this email to fillter record in this way.

> profile_image=
>   ProfileImages.objects.filter(Registration__Email=email).select_related()

let me know what is the exact way to perform this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProfileImages.objects.get(MemeberName__email=email)

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'MemberName' into field. Choices are: MemeberName, MemeberName_id, companies, id, profile_image

Comment: You've misspelled MemberName as MemeberName, unless your users are true memers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it as follows

```
class ProfileImages(models.Model):
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',blank=True,null=True)

...
```

And in the Registration

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    YourName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,verbose_name='email')
    ....
    image_profile = models.ForeignKey(
    ProfileImages, verbose_name='Profile Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Notice, that 'media' word in upload_to it is better to define it in settings.py

Comment: And you must have installed Pillow package.